# elastic search: searching through different fields

Tags: reactjs, typescript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am currently trying to write a query for elastic search on how to handle searching.

As of now, with the code I have:

```
{
    "multi_match": {
        "query": {searchTerm},
        "fields": [
            "first_name",
            "last_name"
        ],
        "type": "cross_fields",
        "operator": "and"
    }
}
```

If the searchTerm is 'Example Bazz' it will return 'Example Bazz'. However, if the search term is 'Example B' I expect it to return 'Example Bar, Example Bazz, Example Boo...'

Can anyone help figure out the correct query for the query string to be acting like a matchPrefix for multiple fields to act as one word?

Answer (score 0):

I did this example. I'm assuming the phrase is in a field.
You can combine queries. I preserve your multi match query  and add a new multi match query with type "[phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types)".

```
POST teste/_doc
{
  "first_name":"Example Bar"
}

GET teste/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Example B",
            "fields": [
              "first_name",
              "last_name"
            ],
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Example B",
            "fields": [
              "first_name",
              "last_name"
            ],
            "type": "phrase_prefix",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: would you say this query also works if it was "first_name": Example, "last_name": Bar, Query: "Example B"